# Are there any stable opensource rich text editor packages that are compatible with django-2?

Tags: django, quill, django-2.0

I have tried tinymce. But, it has dependency of communicating to tinymce site for checking plugins.

Is there any other completely opensource text editor to be used in django 2?

Quill seems not stable for django 2. I need to make changes at serveral places, but still couldn't make it work.

Comment: Maybe: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor.

Comment: Yes, ckeditor seems to be working fine..thanks!

Comment: Great, glad it works for you, I use it on all my projects as well. If I write an answer with this suggestion, will you accept it?

Comment: Yes :) ckeditor is perfect for my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) project, it's really easy to use and actively maintained. It is primarily meant to be used with Django [admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/), but it can also be used [outside of the admin](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#outside-of-django-admin), in your custom templates.

One thing I found very powerful (and I believe not actually documented in `django-ckeditor`) is that you can directly use any of the "original" [CKEditor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/index.html)'s configuration settings within the `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS` dictionary in your `settings.py`.

E.g. if you wanted to set up code highlighting, and you've found CKEditor's option to [change the highlighter theme](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_codesnippet.html#changing-highlighter-theme) is:

```
config.codeSnippet_theme = 'school_book';
```

you would add it directly to the `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS` dictionary:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'your_config_name': {
        ...
        'codeSnippet_theme': 'school_book',
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
                'codesnippet',
                ...
            ]
        )
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks and for the javascript part, do we need to always hardcode the div id of the text editor or write our own logic to use variable names?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question?

Comment: I just got done trying out tinymce and summernote editor for DJango. I tried this one last after reading your post and I wish I had tried it first!

Comment: Can I use django-ckeditor or do I have to pay for the plan mentioned in the website? I am not eligible for free plan..

Comment: @UlviDamirli It seems that CKEditor project has updated their licensing between v4 and v5, but I can't really advise on the legality of usage and what that means for your use case.